# Weird schematic with MOSFET bulk connected to some negative terminal

Tags: mosfet, integrated-circuit, diagram

I found a circuit diagram, which I do not understand. In the diagram below, I bounded a peculiar terminal with a red box. The bulk of m3 and m4 MOSFETs are connected to this negative terminal.

[image: circuit diagram]

My question is, what does this mean? Does this mean that the bulk of m4 and m3 is connected to some terminal that has a potential lower than VSS?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Yes. It's difficult to find MOSFETs with a separate substrate connection nowadays, but there are a few. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/509835/buy-mosfets-with-4-terminals

Comment: Is that perhaps from a textbook on IC design?  The fact that the W/L ratio is being called out rather makes me think that the bulk connection is to the substrate, and it's connected to some magical supply that is always handy -- if you're writing textbooks.

Comment: It's not from a textbook.

Comment: Magical supply!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that it gives the Width to Length ratio indicates it is a design internal to an IC, not one using discrete components.

With devices inside an IC the body is usually connected to the substrate (which in turn is usually the most negative or the most positive voltage available, depending upon the doping, N or P-type).

Answer (score 0):

In silicon layout, you tyoically have access to the FOUR terminals of the MOSFET.

The bulk/tub/well can be manipulated as you wish; some opamps even use the wells as differential inputs.

For rail_rail input opamps, as the gates move up and down with common_mode voltage, the well is left tied to VDD+ for Pchan, or to VDD- (for Nchan), causes the resultant large Vthreshold allows the diffpair to function accurately at and beyond Rail. The term "body effect" describes the tradeoffs.